# What's the idiomatic way of overriding a key binding for a given major-mode (but no other)?

Tags: key-bindings, python, major-mode

I'd like to bind `C-x C-e` to `python-shell-send-region` when I am in python major-mode.

In my config file, I have an add-hook for python mode, but I'd like this keybinding override to be removed/restored when I *exit* python major-mode.

The use-case for this is that I want to be able to switch my *scratch* buffer between modes and for things to continue making sense.

Is there an idiomatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure what you're asking. But it sounds like the answer is to bind your key in the major mode's keymap, not in the `global-map`.

For example, if the keymap for your Python mode is `python-mode-map` then do this:

```lisp
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-e") 'python-shell-send-region)
```

Comment: Ahh, that's exactly it. In the process of running around for a solution, I wasn't seeing the forest for the trees.

(and to explain, I was asking for a hook for when python-mode is exited so that I could restore what was previously bound - quite convoluted and unecessary)

Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: More information here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Keymaps.html#Keymaps